# Loop through an array, and check each item

Tags: ruby

I have an array: `@costumer_request = ['regular', '12/03/2013', '14/03/2013']`.
I need to verify if the first item is 'regular' or 'rewards', then verify if each date of the rest of the array is a weekend.
I did something like this:

```
@costumer_request.each_with_index do |item, index|
  if index[0] == 'regular:'
    if DateTime.parse(index).to_date.saturday? or  DateTime.parse(index).to_date.sunday?
      print "It's a weekend"
    else
      print "It's not a weekend"
    end
  end
end

require 'date'

module HotelReservation

  class Hotel

    HOTELS = {
      :RIDGEWOOD   => 'RidgeWood',
      :LAKEWOOD    => 'LakeWood',
      :BRIDGEWOOD  => 'BridgeWood'
    }

    def weekend?(date)
      datetime = DateTime.parse(date)
      datetime.saturday? || datetime.sunday?
    end

    def find_the_cheapest_hotel(text_file)

      @weekends_for_regular = 0
      @weekdays_for_regular = 0

      @weekends_for_rewards = 0
      @weekdays_for_rewards = 0

      File.open(text_file).each_line do |line|

       @costumer_request = line.delete!(':').split
       @costumer_request = line.delete!(',').split

       #Here I want to process something in each array
       #but if I do something like bellow, it will
       #store the result of the two arrays in the same variable
       #I want to store the result of the first array, process something
       #and then do another thing with the second one, and so on.

       if(@costumer_request.first == 'regular')
         @costumer_request[1..-1].each do |date|
           if (weekend?(date))
            @weekends_for_regular +=1
           else
            @weekdays_for_regular +=1
           end
        end
        else
          if(@costumer_request.first == 'rewards')
            @costumer_request[1..-1].each do |date|
            if (weekend?(date))
              @weekends_for_rewards +=1
            else
              @weekdays_for_rewards +=1
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
end
```

The find_the_cheapest_hotel method should output the cheapest hotel based on the given data.

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: First: check if the costumer is a regular or reward costumer. Second:  check if the given dates are weekends. In case of a weekend show the message "It's a weekend" else, show "It's not a weekend"

Comment: do you want to verify that all dates in the array are weekend days and what do you want to do if the first entry isn't regular or reward? What is the expected output?  True if either matches and all dates are weekend days? or the list of matching days ?

Comment: Yeah for the first question and for the second question I'd say I don't need to verify if the first entry doesn't match to 'regular' or 'rewards', because It's a pattern, It can't be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a really clean way of doing it:

```
def is_weekend?(dt)
  dt.saturday? || dt.sunday?
end

type, *dates = @costumer_request

if(type == 'regular')
  dates.each do |date|
    if(weekend?(Date.parse(date))
      #do processing here
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. *dates = creates an array of dates ? I didn't get this part.

Comment: That line uses the splat operator (*). It sets type to the first element of @customer_request and dates to the reset of the array.

Comment: What if I have an array like this: [['regular', '12/03/2013'], ['regular''12/04/2013'], ['rewards', '12/04/2013']] ? I tried your code in this situation but It did something like this: got the 2 arrays which have regular as the first element and then created an array with all the dates of the two arrays.

Comment: I want that the code shows "It's a weekend" for the two arrays which has 'regular' as its first element"

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting at. If you've got a second scenario, add it to your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'time'
require 'date'
@costumer_request = ['regular', '28/03/2013', '14/03/2013']
if @costumer_request.first == 'regular'
    if @costumer_request[1...-1].all?{|item| Time.local(item).saturday? || Time.local(item).sunday? }
        print "It's a weekend"
    else
        print "It's not a weekend"
    end
end
```

***output:***

```
It's a weekend
```

Comment: You probably want to move the `first` check outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'time'

def weekend?(date)
  datetime = DateTime.parse(date)
  datetime.saturday? || datetime.sunday?
end

@costumer_request = ['regular', '28/03/2013', '14/03/2013']

type = @costumer_request.shift

if type == 'regular'
  @costumer_request.each do |date|
     if weekend?(date)
       puts "#{date} a weekend"
     else
       puts "#{date} not a weekend"
     end
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You may as well add `weekend?` directly to DateTime:

```
class DateTime
  def weekend?
    saturday? || sunday?
  end
end
```

Now you can convert all but the first element to DateTime objects, then check that all of them are on the weekend.

```
if @customer_request.first == 'regular'
  dates = @customer_request[1..-1].map { |date_string| DateTime.parse(date_string) }
  if dates.all?(&:weekend?)
    puts 'all dates on a weekend'
  else
    puts 'at least one date is not on a weekend'
  end
else
  puts 'not a regular customer request'
end
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@customer_request = ['regular', '12/03/2013', '14/03/2013']



def val
  @customer_request.first == 'regular' &&
    @customer_request.drop(1).inject(true)  do |m, e|
      wd = Time.local(*e.split('/').reverse.map(&:to_i))
      m &&= (wd.saturday? || wd.sunday?)
    end
end


p val
p val ? 'all are weekends' : 'something isn\'t a weekend'
```

Comment: why do you assign the instance variable to a single letter variable name? This is completely unreadable.